# How to turn the whole cross-reference into blue color and hyperlink when using \crefformat in cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, hyperlink

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks, colorlinks, linktocpage=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue}
\newcommand\pcref[1]{(\cref{#1})}
\newcommand\qcref[1]{\cref({#1})}
\crefformat{figure}{(figure~#2#1#3)}
\Crefformat{figure}{figure~#2#1#3}
\crefformat{table}{(table~#2#1#3)}
\Crefformat{table}{table~#2#1#3}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!] \caption{bar}\label{fig:bar}\end{figure}
\Cref{fig:bar}, 
\Cref{fig:bar},
\cref{fig:bar},
\cref{fig:bar}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the low-level commands `\crefformat` and `\Crefformat`, the markers `#2` and `#3` delimit the extent of the material that is turned into a hypertarget. In order to achieve your formatting goal, you'll need to change `\crefformat{figure}{(figure~#2#1#3)}` to `\crefformat{figure}{#2(figure~#1)#3}` to make the hypertarget include the parentheses (and the string "figure", of course). If you do *not* wish to make the parentheses form part of the hypertarget, just use `\crefformat{figure}{(#2figure~#1#3)}` instead.

Observe that because `\crefformat` and `\Crefformat` give you total control over the formatting, the package option `nameinlink` doesn't have an effect. Of course, the option will have an effect for cross-references to other objects, such as `equation` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefformat{figure}{#2(figure~#1)#3}
\Crefformat{figure}{#2Figure~#1#3}
\crefformat{table}{#2(table~#1)#3}
\Crefformat{table}{#2Table~#1#3}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!] \caption{bar}\label{fig:bar}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!]  \caption{foo}\label{tab:foo}\end{table}

\Cref{fig:bar}, \Cref{tab:foo}, \cref{fig:bar}, \cref{tab:foo}.
\end{document}
```